# Homework Java - Syntax error, cannot invoke method in array.

Tags: java, class, getter-setter

I have a homework assignment where I take input from users for radius and height of a cylinder, then return the volume. I have most of it done I think, but am having trouble bringing it all together. I am getting a syntax error when I try to print it all out. Here is the print line

```
for (int i = 0; i < volume.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("for Radius of:" + volume[i].getRadius() + " and Height of:" + volume[i].getHeight() + " the Volume is:" + volume.getVolume());
}
```

Here is the main class

```
import javax.swing.*;

//Driver class
public class CylinderTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Cylinder[] volume = new Cylinder[3];
        for (int counter = 0; counter < volume.length; counter++)
        {
            double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter the radius"));
            double height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter the height"));
            volume[counter] = new Cylinder(radius, height);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < volume.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("for Radius of:" + volume[i].getRadius() + " and Height of:" + volume[i].getHeight() + " the Volume is:" + volume.getVolume());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Cylinder class

```
public class Cylinder
{
    // variables
    public static final double PI = 3.14159;
    private double radius, height, volume;

    // constructor
    public Cylinder(double radius, double height)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.height = height;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    // default constructor
    public Cylinder()
    {this(0, 0);}

    // accessors and mutators (getters and setters)
    public double getRadius()
    {return radius;}

    private void setRadius(double radius)
    {this.radius = radius;}

    public double getHeight()
    {return height;}

    private void setHeight(double height)
    {this.height = height;}

    public double getVolume()
    {return volume;}

    // Volume method to compute the volume of the cylinder
    public double volume()
    {return PI * radius * radius * height;}

    public String toString()
    {return volume + "\t" + radius + "\t" + height; }

}
```

I am trying to get the volume from the Cylinder class getVolume getter.

Comment: Try to add the exact error, my IDE says this: `Cannot invoke getVolume() on the array type Cylinder[]` It is trying to getVolume from the array not from a Cylinder instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite easy, you're missing something here:

`volume.getVolume()`

should be `volume[i].getVolume()`

`volume` is the array, while `volume[i]` is an instance of your `Cylinder` class.

As a side note, instead of defining PI in a constant, you can use `Math.PI` which is already defined (and more accurate).

Updated answer:
In your Cylinder class, you are initializing the `volume` variable to 0. I suggest you remove the `volume` variable and the `getVolume` method. And instead of calling the `getVolume` method you should call the `volume()` method. Computing the volume is very fast, you don't need to store it as a variable in the class.

Comment: `while volume[i] is a Cylinder instance *`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately now it returning 0.0 for all the answers
  `for (int i = 0; i < volume.length; i++)
  {
   System.out.println("for Radius of:" + volume[i].getRadius() + " and Height of:" + volume[i].getHeight() + " the Volume is:" + volume[i].getVolume());
  }`

`// Volume method to compute the volume of the cylinder
 public double volume()
 {return PI * radius * radius * height;}`

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg. It is working great now. I just need to add some data validation and formatting, which I will be able to do on my own. But I want to say thank you so much for your help. I have been working for days on this, struggling with these concepts. I am so thankful to you and all the others on this board who have the heart of a teacher.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
volume.getVolume()
```

Use

```
volume[i].getVolume()
```

You were using the array instead of the **element** of the array - and the array didn't have a `getVolume()` method... That understandably results in a syntax error...

Answer (score 1):

`volume` is an array (of `Cylindar`), so it doesn't have your method `getVolume`.  You probably want `volume[i].getVolume`, since that's the cylindar object you are referencing in the rest of the print statement.